# getting error : ‘Foam::solverPersistentData<Foam::lduMesh, Foam::GPUSolverData>::typeName’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, openfoam

while executing ./Allwmake getting the ambiguous error. error is given below.

```
Found nvcc  --  enabling CUDA support.
SOURCE=lduMatrixConversion/lduMatrixConversion.C ;  g++ -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/home/suraj/ispm-sparse-lib-master -isystem /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include  -IlnInclude -I. -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -c $SOURCE -o Make/linux64Gcc48DPOpt/lduMatrixConversion.o
SOURCE=GPUPCG/GPUPCG.C ;  g++ -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/home/suraj/ispm-sparse-lib-master -isystem /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include  -IlnInclude -I. -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -c $SOURCE -o Make/linux64Gcc48DPOpt/GPUPCG.o
SOURCE=AsyncPrecondProvider/AsyncPrecondProvider.C ;  g++ -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/home/suraj/ispm-sparse-lib-master -isystem /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include  -IlnInclude -I. -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -c $SOURCE -o Make/linux64Gcc48DPOpt/AsyncPrecondProvider.o
SOURCE=GPUSolverData/GPUSolverData.C ;  g++ -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/home/suraj/ispm-sparse-lib-master -isystem /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include  -IlnInclude -I. -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -c $SOURCE -o Make/linux64Gcc48DPOpt/GPUSolverData.o
In file included from /home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.H:281,
                 from lnInclude/solverPersistentData.H:43,
                 from GPUPCG/GPUPCG.H:43,
                 from GPUPCG/GPUPCG.C:32:
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.C: In static member function ‘static const Type& Foam::MeshObject<Mesh, MeshObjectType, Type>::New(const Mesh&) [with Mesh = Foam::lduMesh, MeshObjectType = Foam::UpdateableMeshObject, Type = Foam::solverPersistentData<Foam::lduMesh, Foam::GPUSolverData>]’:
GPUPCG/GPUPCG.C:65:   instantiated from here
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.C:48: error: reference to ‘Foam::solverPersistentData<Foam::lduMesh, Foam::GPUSolverData>::typeName’ is ambiguous
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/IOobject.H:177: error: candidates are: const Foam::word Foam::IOobject::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/regIOobject.H:125: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::regIOobject::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.H:168: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::meshObject::typeName
lnInclude/solverPersistentData.H:66: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::solverPersistentDataName::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.C:59: error: reference to ‘Foam::solverPersistentData<Foam::lduMesh, Foam::GPUSolverData>::typeName’ is ambiguous
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/IOobject.H:177: error: candidates are: const Foam::word Foam::IOobject::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/regIOobject.H:125: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::regIOobject::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.H:168: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::meshObject::typeName
lnInclude/solverPersistentData.H:66: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::solverPersistentDataName::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/MeshObject.C:65: error: reference to ‘Foam::solverPersistentData<Foam::lduMesh, Foam::GPUSolverData>::typeName’ is ambiguous
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/IOobject.H:177: error: candidates are: const Foam::word Foam::IOobject::typeName
/home/suraj/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/regIOobject.H:125: error:                 const Foam::word Foam::regIOobject::typeName
```

and most of the errors are due to ambiguity in the code.
the files are used from OpenFOAM2.4.x distriution. which are available online.

Comment: Which architecture are you on? Is there a particular reason why you are going for OpenFOAM 2.4.x?

Comment: sm_30. The reason behind using OpenFOAM 2.4.x is the latest one.

Comment: It's definitely not the latest one: http://openfoam.org/version3.0.1/

Comment: when i have started development then this one is new. now i can not change it.

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to discuss why it's always good to use the latest version of either vanilla OpenFOAM or foam-extend, if you are don't need any features that only available in those versions :). Do yourself a favor and spend a little time to port your code to the latest vanilla version of OpenFOAM. There are some significant development jumps from the 2.x versions to the 3 versions, which you should really leverage. Before you try to port your code, just download the latest OpenFOAM version and test if it compiles.

Comment: Since this the OpenFOAM library is quite large, I highly doubt that you will have to change anything in the vanilla sources to make it compile. Hence my question: what are you aiming for? Have you changed the vanilla code directly or have you implemented your own code in your own individual executable/library? These compilation errors of the vanilla code are usually configuaration issues of the host systems (GCC version, flex version, etc.)

Comment: these are individual library code developed apart from OpenFOAM distribution

Comment: So a custom library for 2.4 is causing this problem, is that right?

Comment: yes. When I call ./Allwmake

Comment: If you just post the error message, we will not be able to help you, please post a minimal example of the code that is causing the trouble. The error message can be caused by a lot of things.

Comment: you can see OpenFOAM code here https://github.com/surajpsalvi/OpenFOAM2.4.x_CUDA/tree/master/OpenFOAM-2.4.x
and 
Location where i am executing ./Allwmake -  https://github.com/surajpsalvi/OpenFOAM2.4.x_CUDA/tree/master/OpenFOAM-2.4.x/src/ispmCudaSolvers

Comment: So it's no custom code. What is it now? You said earlier that it is a custom library. Anyway, if I find some time today, I will try to compile the CUDA version of 2.4.x, but no promises.

Comment: I had a look and now you really need to explain what you did. I suspect that you've put *your* code (`ispmCudaSolver`) into the *vanilla* OpenFOAM 2.4.x repository, which you have copied entierely. Can you please give more information in your question, otherwise there is no way of helping.

Comment: Have you developed that library (`ispmCudaSolver`) library on your own, or did receive it from some third party? In the latter case, ask them for assistance? Going through that library is not going to happen, since it is quite large for SO questions, I had a look at it.

Comment: @Suraij: If you would like to assist us in backing us with our OpenFOAM Stackexchange page, please consider commiting at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88229/openfoam-technology?referrer=wKk_iyAzdt_JZPwokb1I_w2 we can really need any help.